# Typography.com whitelisted but not AMP ready

Tags: amp-html

I use cloud.Typography.com for my webfonts, as it was whitelisted by Google AMP. 
However, they don't work. I asked why this was to Typography and their response:

```
Thank you for getting in touch. This is Sarah from H&Co, and I help with the technical side of things here.
Our webfont are currently not supported by Google AMP pages. We do appreciate your feedback on this and working on an integration somewhere in the near future.
```

Why does Google whitelist this font when it isn't available?

Comment: Hi, could you post your code?

Comment: You may refer with this [related issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3749). It stated that the prefix `https://cloud.typography.com/is` should be fine. also, be sure the domain is properly whitelisted at typography.com, including the https version if it exists and any sub-domains. Check it [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5844).

Comment: @abielita   Hi, it works on my domain. It just doesn't load when it is loaded by Google's cache.
Do I have to add google.com.au to the list of domains in my typography account?

Answer (score 1):

Their mention was removed from the AMP side. They requested whitelisting, but ended up not following through with the implementation.